# Laravel 5.4 Storage : downloading files. File does not exist, but clearly it does

Tags: laravel

I have been going round and round with this. I have uploads working with the follow:

```
public function store(Tool $tool)
{

     If(Input::hasFile('file')){
        $file = Input::file('file');
        $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $path=Storage::put('public',$file);         //Storage::disk('local')->put($name,$file,'public');

        $file = new File;
        $file->tool_id = $tool->id;
        $file->file_name = $name;
        $file->path_to_file = $path;
        $file->name_on_disk = basename($path);
        $file->user_name = \Auth::user()->name;
        $file->save();

        return back();
    }
```

however when I try to download with:

```
public function show($filename)
    {   

        $url = Storage::disk('public')->url($filename);

        ///$file = Storage::disk('public')->get($filename);
        return response()->download($url);
    }
```

I get the FileNotFound exception from laravel
However, if I use this instead:

```
$file = Storage::disk('public')->get($filename);
return response()->download($file);
```

I get

> FileNotFoundException in File.php line 37: The file "use calib;
>
> insert into
>   notes(`tool_id`,`user_id`,`note`,`created_at`,`updated_at`)
>   VALUES(1,1,'windows server 2008 sucks',now(),now());" does not exist

which is the actual content of the file...

It can obviously find the file. but why wont it download?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try this:

```
return response()->download(storage_path("app/public/{$filename}"));
```

Comment: This actually worked. But why? Doesnt is seem as though adding the actual Facade of Storage, and getting the freaking URL would work? or Rather the fact that I am also including the damn symbolic link etc. Glad it worked. thanks for the help. The documentation doesnt really help at all. I have tried all kinds of things, even went as far as looking at the source for the underlying class for the Facade etc. Your including the storage path, but also including the path to the storage path - in a way.

Comment: From the laravel documentation: 
`The url function generates a fully qualified URL to the given path` but in the `response()->download()` method, you need the filepath and not the fully qualified URL

Comment: This doesn't work if you are using a different storage disk though. Any idea how to deal with it using the Storage facade? We use Azure in production and local for development so need to have a way to make it work for both.

Comment: This only works because you create a symbolic link but if you are using the storage facade because you do not want to have private files available through the URL this does not work with version 5.5 and below of laravel.

Comment: @natral the storage facade doesn't make files private. It depends on the driver you use. `Storage::disk('public')` still refers to public files despite using the storage facade. And you need to make a symbolic link for even the facade to work. This answer is not for private files - refer OP's question.

Answer (score 7):

Replace:

```
$file = Storage::disk('public')->get($filename);
return response()->download($file);
```

With:

```
return response()->download(storage_path('app/public/' . $filename));
```

`response()->download()` takes a path to a file, not a file content. More information here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/responses#file-downloads

Comment: I have tried to do that before. That exact thing. It tells me that the file does not exist.

Comment: thanks. Yes I know it takes a path. I gave it a path but it said it didnt find it. I only included the portion of the $file so that you could see that it returned the contents of the file. Thus, it could find the file

Comment: memory overload?

Answer (score 4):

If any one still could not find their file even though the file clearly exists then try

```
return response()->file(storage_path('/app/' . $filename, $headers));
```

It could be due to a missing directory separator or it isn't stored inside the public folder.

Comment: This was the reason for me as well, missing 'app' in the storage_path. Laravel 7